# Where to include arguments for invocation of state-changing function

Tags: contract-invocation

I have this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 
contract Proof { 
    function register(bytes32 hash) { 
        if (hashToDate[hash] != 0) return; 
        hashToDate[hash] = now; 

    } 
    function dateOf(bytes32 hash) constant returns (uint date) { 
        return hashToDate[hash]; 

    } 
    mapping (bytes32 => uint) hashToDate; 
}
```

I deployed this contract successfully. I can call `dateOf` successfully as well, since it is a constant function (return value `0` is intended, since the hash has not been `register`ed, yet):

```
> proof.dateOf("0x492...fee7d")
0
```

Now I want to call `register(bytes32)`.

This is what I have from the documentation, but I don't know where to include the argument.

```
var tx = proof.register.sendTransaction(proof.address, 0, {from:eth.accounts[0]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proof.register.sendTransaction(hashToRegister, {from:eth.accounts[0]})`

Which can just be:

`proof.register(hashToRegister, {from:eth.accounts[0]})`

Because `register` is not labelled `constant`.